# how we can call one chaincode from another chaincode in fabric 1.0 ?? if anyone having example please share

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to call one chaincode from another chaincode in fabric 1.0
so I have some questions:
1) can we install two chaincode on single peer
2) if we install two chaincode on different peer, how we can call one into another?
3)if anybody having sample example please share.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is should be pretty straight forward to achieve, here is an example:

```
// Invoke
func (am *accountManagement) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    actionName, params := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

    if actionName == "callAnotherCC" {
        chainCodeArgs := util.ToChaincodeArgs("anotherCCFunc", "paramA")
        response := stub.InvokeChaincode("anotherCCName", chainCodeArgs, "channelName")

        if response.Status != shim.OK {
           return shim.Error(response.Message)
        }
        return shim.Success(nil)
    }

    // NOTE: This is an example, hence assuming only valid call is to call another chaincode
    return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR] No <%s> action defined", actionName))
}
```

---

**UPDTAE**

As @Gari, correctly stated in the comment:

> It's very important to make sure that both chaincodes are installed on each endorsing peer

Consider to read also following material:

1. https://github.com/asararatnakar/fabric_v1_Chaincode_instructions/blob/master/call-chaincode-to-chaincode-nondefault-chain.md
2. https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1788
3. http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/chaincode.html

Comment: @ArtemBarger Can I call chaincode of other channel?

Comment: @AkshaySood only if peer participates in both channels and has second chaincode installed.