# Is it possible to access a GO lang chaincode from Hyperledger Composer script file

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

This might seem like a weird question . But i want to know if it is possible to access a **GO language chaincode** installed in the peers from **Composer** script file .

That is in script.js file of the BNA file is it possible to access the GO Lang chaincode installed in the peers from Hyperledger Fabric side .

I want to invoke a chaincode 'mycc' from the script.js file and try to call 'mycc' functions from Composer

Any suggestions?
Also an example would be good . Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to invoke another chaincode from a Composer transaction script.  You would need to use the `getNativeAPI()` function.  It is introduced in the Composer documentation halfway down in [this document](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts) where I think the example uses the native api to access the 'current' network (chaincode).

There is an additional example in [this tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/invoke-composer-network) where the `getNativeAPI().invokeChaincode` method is used to connect to a different Business Network.

I have not seen other examples, but this should work for connecting to other chaincodes.

Comment: So you are saying i can do something like getNativeAPI().invokeChaincode('mycc',channelID,<somefunction in GO chaincode>)  ?

Comment: there is an example here of invokeChaincode (and observe the caveats pointed out there - it mentions 1.0 obviously you're using a later Fabric version) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360796/how-we-can-call-one-chaincode-from-another-chaincode-in-fabric-1-0-if-anyone  The parameters for invokeChaincode are shown here :  https://fabric-shim.github.io/ChaincodeStub.html#invokeChaincode

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony this link is useful .my question is will i able to do this from my javascript file in composer .go to go code is possible . javascript to go ? if so then great .

Comment: yes, in your script .js file, you can call your go chaincode and should be able to pass arguments to select which specific chaincode function it wants to invoke.