# Hyperledger Fabric Cross Communication

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

Is it possible to have one client or peer to be part of two different hyperledger fabric networks (where each network has it own orderer, Fabric CA, etc.)?
The reason I'm asking is I want to make two different hyperledger fabric network to be able to communicate and execute chaincodes from one network to another (cross-communication).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to have an endorsing peer participate in 2 different networks (e.g. a supply chain blockchain n/w and a logistics blockchain n/w) both of which have a separate smart contract. Here, the joint peer will have 2 ledgers from both n/w and can make a transaction in both chains who have different orderer and CA. You have to set up the right read and write transaction permissions for this endorsing peer accordingly in yaml file and have right certificates.

Check these links: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/peers/peers.html
https://www.skcript.com/svr/setting-hyperledger-fabric-network-multiple-chaincodes-channels/

Cross communicating between 2 chains should be possible like a certain transaction on a chain invokes the other Business Network Archive. Check out this answer: [how we can call one chaincode from another chaincode in fabric 1.0 ?? if anyone having example please share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360796/how-we-can-call-one-chaincode-from-another-chaincode-in-fabric-1-0-if-anyone)

But to see the way like a transaction in one chain invokes transaction in other chain is kinda tricky. AFAIK, you won't be able to see 2 separate transactions in a transaction registry.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I have only one concern, where do I need to set up the right r/w permissions for the transactions. should I do that within yaml thats runs the peer or in a separate yaml file?

Comment: you can set read and write permission in acl (access control language) file as set of rules which work as authorization. And, you need to have an identity associated with the peer which works like authentication. Identities are generated using Fabric's CA (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/managing/identity-issue). In this case, there'll be 2 separate ids associated to same peer. P.S. yml file I mentioned is crypto-config.yaml to generate certificates which are in turn used in identity for peer.

Comment: AFAIK, you can call a read/write operation from one chaincode onto another chaincode as long as both of them belong to the same channel. For chaincodes installed on different channels within the same network, cross-chaincode write operations are not possible, read is.

Comment: To perform write request between chaincodes on different channels, is it possible  to change the source code of the invokeChaincode function or any other function to achieve it ?